# Why is there no direct message widget on my Galaxy S6 stock?

Tags: sms, 5.1-lollipop, app-widgets, samsung-galaxy-s-6

On a brand new Samsung Galaxy S6 in Europe with Android 5.1.1 and Nova Launcher there are widgets for adding a shortcut into a contact and to call a contact's phone number, but the one for text messages/SMS that I know from older versions. On my S5 with 5.0 I have this widget. I have not installed an additional messaging app that replaces the stock SMS application.

How do I get a shortcut for sending SMS to a contact?

[image: On Android 5.0 the widget is there (with free hand circle!)] [image: On Adroid 5.1.1 the widget is missing]
<sup>On Android 5.0, the widget is there (1st pic) | On Android 5.1.1, it's not (2nd pic) – click images to enlarge</sup>

Comment: I'm afraid it's related to Samsung's decision (for god knows why), their TouchWiz, and seems it's the case (same issue on [AndroidCentral forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/513943-add-direct-dial-shortcut.html#post4382113)) "*Samsung removed the direct dial shortcut for no apparent reason in their lollipop update. It is also missing from the TouchWiz launcher.*"

Comment: @beeshyams there is no widgets tab. This is Nova Launcher, but even with tabs turned on no widgets tab appears.

Comment: @AndrewT this is Nova Launcher, but it also didn't bring it apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

It seems this is an issue specific to some Samsung Galaxy S-series devices running Android 5.1.1 Lollipop. There's nothing we can't do other than waiting for update from Samsung (if it's really a bug).

---

I believe it's either a bug, or Samsung's decision to remove "Direct Message" widget (for unknown reason) from their Contacts app. There were some reports about this issue.

From [a post on AndroidCentral forum](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/513943-add-direct-dial-shortcut.html#post4382113),

> I've been trading support emails with the Nova folks. According to them, "Samsung removed the direct dial shortcut for no apparent reason in their Lollipop update. It is also missing from the TouchWiz launcher."

[Another thread](http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-5-0-lollipop/570027-why-aren-t-contacts-acting-same-my-s5-4-4-android.html) also asked the same issue,

> I just upgraded to the S6 and it has Android 5.1.1.
> There are a few things I can't figure out.
> [...]
> 3. How can I set up Direct Dial shortcut on home screen and Direct Message? [...]

And lastly, on [T-Mobile forum](https://support.t-mobile.com/thread/95878?start=0&tstart=0) which gives hint on not carrier-specific,

> My wife and I both have the S5 on 5.1.1 (F0G6) and both have this problem since the update. It happens for Direct Message shortcuts/widgets too. It appears to be a TouchWiz bug (guessing) since changing Launchers to something like Nova keeps the shortcut ... It is a small thing but a big problem for me - help!
>
> My best friend has Verizon, and hers are disappearing as well, so I don't think it's a T-Mobile issue, I think it's an OS issue.

Which was replied with,

> This is a known issues. Both T-Mobile and Samsung are trying to find out what is causing it and fix

Comment: I kind of believe it's possible to use 3rd-party apps, but I haven't researched for the alternatives yet.

Comment: Thanks for finding the references. I just read all of those quotes in your links as well. A quick search didn't yield any alternatives, but I will do more thorough research later.

Comment: I've asked for alternatives [here](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/29890/1107).